# Angular 5 eliminar componentes hermanos al iniciar

Tags: angular, angular5

Tengo la siguiente estructura en componente padre app.component

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>  
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

en router-outlet se cargan los componentes dinamicos (home, contacto etc). Tengo un componente llamado login, que se carga con router-outlet. He intentado de muchas formas hacer que que al cargar login elimine app-header y app-footer pero no encuentro la forma.
¿Como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: ngIf ? con alguna variable booleana que indique si se está mostrando el Login

Comment: amigo yo tengo el mismo problema como lo haria en el app saludos

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurren dos soluciones:

### 1. Que el componente Login no esté dentro de ese "layout".

Podrías hacer algo como

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },   // Main redirect
    {
        path: '',
        children: [
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
            { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        component: LayoutComponent,
        children: [
            //... resto de componentes
        ]
    }
```

donde LayoutComponent es el que tiene como template

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>  
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

### 2. Usar `*ngIf` para decidir si se usan los otros componentes, teniendo un atributo en el componente app para decidir si mostrar el encabezado o no.

```
    <app-header *ngIf="mostrar"></app-header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>  
    <app-footer *ngIf="mostrar"></app-footer>
```